# Volly JsonArrayRequest not getting data from Laravel website

Tags: php, android, laravel

I am trying to get jsonArray from my laravel site using volly in android application, but iam getting nothing, even errorlistner method does not get fired. 
I know something is wrong from returned laravel response but i cannot figured it. Please some one visit both url and point what is missing. I get correct jsonArray while debuging if i swap the request with second url . Here are both url

```
//this returns nothing in Volly  .
public static String urlPath = "http://staging.megabix.com/api/v1/terms/1/subTerms"

//This one works fine

public static String urlPath = "http://shakeelnawaz.com/soccerquiz/process.php?action=show_category";
```

Following is my code for volly request

```
public void JSON_HTTP_CALL() {

    RequestOfJSonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_JSON_URL,

            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("shahid", "onResponse: "+response);

                    ParseJSonResponse(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("shahid", "Error getting Response: ");

                }
            });
```

On my Laravel website i am using this code.

```
public function getSubTerms(Term $term){
    $subTerms= $term->subTerms;
    $a=$subTerms;

    //This does not work in volly
     return $a;

    //Nor this worked
    return response()->json($a,200);
```

I shall be very thankful if someone can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is way of calling is error not php error i will give the code try then let me know just now i tried friend.

```
public void JSON_HTTP_CALL() {
    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String urlPath = "http://staging.megabix.com/api/v1/terms/1/subTerms";


    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlPath,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "That work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "That didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

you need create RequestQueue Object first Thank you try and let me know.

And one thing in Manifest file did add this line make sure

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot to solve my issue and  point of creating Request Queue  first. Bundle of Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need return JsonEncoded String after getting data in android just convert Array Object.

Comment: I think laravel directly returns Json response so it would be already a  json array. please check the response being returned [Here](http://staging.megabix.com/api/v1/terms/1/subTerms) . it seems ok to me . pls let me know what is wrong with that returned json array.